# why reflection GetMethod return null?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to create an instance of object dynamically and execute one method of this instance dynamically. I am trying this code but **GetMethod** return null.

```
var className = "SomeClass";
Type[] paramTypes = { typeof(Telegram.Bot.Types.User), typeof(string[]) };
var cmd = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "mynamespace." + className);
var method = cmd.GetType().GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance, null, paramTypes, null);
res = method.Invoke(cmd, new object[] { e.Message.From, args }).ToString();
```

and this is my SomeClass code:

```
public class RegisterTelegramCommand : ITelegramCommand
{
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return "some message"; 
        }
    }

    public string Execute(Telegram.Bot.Types.User telegramUser, string[] param)
    {
        return param[0]+" " +param[2];           
    }
}
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: also paste code of `SomeClass`?

Comment: Is the Execute method private or static?

Comment: no it is not. it is a public method.

Comment: Does `GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` return anything? If so, you have a parameter type mismatch. If not, your class is lacking the method entirely.

Comment: it return null.

Comment: Log out `cmd.GetType()` and see if it’s actually your type…

Comment: yes it is. it has Message property in wrappedObject inside cmd

Comment: What if you try `GetMethods` instead of `GetMethod`? Does it get it?

Comment: Did you tried just to call `GetMethod("Execute")`?

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 *“it has Message property in wrappedObject inside cmd”* – How is that a confirmation that this is your actual exact type `RegisterTelegramCommand` you are showing here? And what is `wrappedObject`?

Comment: Follow @Gulam answer and unwrap it, then it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have putted parameter null, might be due that this issue is comming,  I have check this in console code is working fine

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var className = "RegisterTelegramCommand";
            Type[] paramTypes = { typeof(object), typeof(string[]) };
            var cmd = Activator.CreateInstance("ConsoleApplication4", "ConsoleApplication4." + className);
            Object p = cmd.Unwrap();
            var method = p.GetType().GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, paramTypes, null);
            var res = method.Invoke(p, new object[] { null, args }).ToString();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class RegisterTelegramCommand
    {
        public string Message
        {
            get { return "a"; }
        }

        public string Execute(object paramObject, string[] param)
        {
            return param[0] + " " + param[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change namespace and parameters value properly

Comment: If you think this code is needed, please update your other answer instead of posting a new one. You can offer this code as a "second option" of your first one.

Comment: Sorry I have Just start the sharing of my knowledge, Sure I will improve in the same.

Answer (score 2):

[`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) returns a [`ObjectHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.aspx) which needs to be unwrapped first:

```
var className = "RegisterTelegramCommand";

Type[] paramTypes = { typeof(object), typeof(string[]) };
var cmd = Activator.CreateInstance("ConsoleApplication4", "ConsoleApplication4." + className);
Object p = cmd.Unwrap();
var method = p.GetType().GetMethod("Execute", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, paramTypes, null);
var res = method.Invoke(p, new object[] { null, args }).ToString();
```

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: it solve my problem in null pointer exception but i am getting this exception now: System.Reflection.TargetException

Comment: i test your code in some test project it worked perfectly but still i have exception in main project\

Comment: can you share some part of your project code if possible for identifying exact issue in the same